Merge point cloud 3dtileset (entwine, pdal)
Is there a way to delete and add areas of new point cloud data (las files) to an existing built 3Dtileset?
Current Status

We are visualizing point cloud data with 3Dtileset data created with ept-tools.
I built the las file into entwine.(entwine build -i crop.las -o output_folder)
3Dtileset was created by specifying ept.json as epttile.(ept tile .\ept.json --force)

